# Access SMB Share From .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, maui, smb

I have an app previously written using WPF. This is used in a single physical location. The database is SQL Server (accessed with EF Core), but documents are associated with records. In the WPF app, these documents are stored on a Windows 2019 Server with domain-level authentication on an SMB share.

I've moved most of my application to MAUI which is looking really good so far. I've got EF Core working just as I want it, but I'm unsure how to access the documents on the SMB share from my Android devices. The aim is obviously as much platform-independence as possible but I'm aware that for this sort of thing I'll probably need platform specific code. The FileSystem helpers seem too high-level to achieve what I want to achieve.

How do I achieve this? I'm prepared to store documents on a secure cloud-based service but don't have a huge recurring budget.

Comment: there are many existing questions and SMB and Xamarin which should largely apply to MAUI too.  https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+smb+site%253Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Perfect thank you. This is a gap my Google-fu! I use WPF and have recently started with MAUI. Never used Xamarin but it didn't cross my mind to search for solutions using that. Thanks again.